# Ability to view text in each class

Tags: java, android, text

Recently, I program for the Android platform. I have a question about the text.
Is there any way to display the text **without using the XML**?
I also want the text to be able to show in each class.

Comment: You have a question about *which* text?  It is't clear to me what "the text" refers to.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if you can replace the text of anything programatically, yes you can. Usually, you have a `setText` method you can use for that. I'd advise you to read [the tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) and [the javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) to know more about this.